# Setting volume on embedded vimeo video with javascript api

Tags: javascript, android, volume, vimeo-api, embedded-video

I am trying to create the following scenario with a responsive embedded vimeo video:

- **When volume controls are available, start with volume 0**
- **When volume controls are not available, start with volume 1**

This is the current code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
    var vimeo_intro_video_options = {
        id: /* video_id */,
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
    };

    var vimeo_intro_video = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-intro-video', vimeo_intro_video_options);

    // Set Volume to 0
    vimeo_intro_video.setVolume(0);
  }
});
```

The problem with this is that some mobile devices allow setting the volume and some dont, but none of them have volume controls in the player. Therefore I end up with a muted video on some devices even though the user has volume turned on (only Android so far).

One possible solution would be to use `userAgent` to detect mobile devices and not set the volume there. Is there a better way?